# Alternate content of a div every 3 seconds with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to alternate the contents of a div (or swap in a new div if better) every few seconds, with a fade in/out. Jquery prefered, or pure js fine too.

Based on Arun's solution, I have added the Jquery below, and it works perfectly... but **how do I make it repeat?**

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="height:100px">
  <div id="quote1">I am a quote</div>
  <div id="quote2">I am another quote</div>
  <div id="quote3">I am yet another quote</div>
</div>
```

Javascript: (as per Arun in the comments)

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $els = $('div[id^=quote]'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
            $els.eq(++i % len).fadeIn();
        })
    }, 2500)
})
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/asTBL/1/

Comment: Have any of our answers worked for you?

Comment: I really like @Arun P Johny's solution, because it's so succinct. How to make it repeat?

Comment: Could downvoter please provide reason for downvote?

Comment: I downvoted the OP for the reason in my comment, not sure who's downvoting the answers. It's probably because they're just throwing solutions at you instead of actually helping you, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $els = $('div[id^=quote]'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
            i = (i + 1) % len
            $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
        })
    }, 2500)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/asTBL/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```
jQuery(function () {
var $els = $('div[id^=quote]'),
    i = 0,
    len = $els.length;

$els.slice(1).hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
        i = (i + 1) % len
        $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
    })
}, 2500)
})
```

Comment: You should explain why OP's code doesn't work and / or what you did in your code.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a job for...a slider. There are a ton of jQuery plugin options out there, 
I've always been a fan of Malsup

[jQuery plugins by malsup](http://jquery.malsup.com/)

he even has responsive ones ready to go. Google "jQuery slider" to be overwhelmed with options.

Comment: I don't really think someone should be touching JQuery when they struggle with simple things like this.

Comment: The OP specifically requested jQuery, and the malsup plugins are pretty easy to use.

Comment: Just so I can understand,  why was this answer downvoted? The post specifically asked for a jQuery solution to transition multiple content elements with a fade at a set increment. I dont know what better constitutes the use of a slideshow, and I suggested a tried and tested plugin with a simple API. The OP never mentioned not wanting to use a plugin,  So exactly why does this solution deserve a downvote?

Comment: Someone seems to be spraying a lot of downvotes around on this question. Or maybe I've unknowingly wandered into a contentious area, although it seems too simple for that to be it. Anyway, your solution does not deserve a downvote in my books, so I tried to even it out:)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it if you set your second and third divs to `hidden`:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('#quote1').fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('fast').delay(6000);
    }, 0);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('#quote2').fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('fast').delay(6000);
    }, 3000);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('#quote3').fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('fast').delay(6000);
    }, 6000);
}, 3000);
```

It's not going to do exactly what you want because fading takes time, so two divs will be onscreen at the same time. I tried to remedy this by having them `fadeIn()` slowly and `fadeOut()` quickly, but I'd recommend taking out the fading altogether and just hiding them.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/NkkN2/).

Also, @ArunPJohny has a solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/asTBL/1/) that is a bit difficult to understand but does get rid of the fading delay problem. Alternatively, here's my [no-fading solution](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/4jFzL/).

Comment: Thanks for this. The fade-in/out is important, and rather than hammer away at this one, I think one of the others with fade as an option will work better for me.

Comment: Thanks again. I do like @ArunPJohny's solution, just looking for a way to have it repeat indefinitely.

Comment: at least it's not just me. usually is:)

Answer (score 0):

Use a slider plugin there are lots on the internet. This is a simple snippet I wrote that works with any number of elements without having to change the javascript.

It's very easy to change.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ux9cD/39/

```
var count = 0;
 $('.wrapper div').css('opacity', '0');
var varName = setInterval(function() {
    //hide all the divs or set opacity to 0
 $('.wrapper div').css('opacity', '0');   
       //get length
       var length = $('.wrapper div').length;    
      //get first child:
       var start =  $('.wrapper div').eq(count);
    if (count < length) {
        animateThis(start,length,count);
       count++;

    } else {
       console.log('end of list');
        //restore back to hidden
        //set count back to 0
            $('.wrapper div').css('opacity', '0');
        count = 0;
    }
}, 2000);
varName;


function animateThis(start,length,count)
{

    $( start ).animate({
  opacity: 1
}, 1000, "linear", function() {
 //return count++;

});


}
```

Comment: This is too much for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here is something you can try if you can do without fade in and fadeout. Just a simple few lines of java script no need to add any plugins etc.

Also look at this link [Jquery delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) it has sample with delay and fade in fadeout. May be you can tailor it to your needs.

**Try in your browser**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

function swapDiv(){
    var firstString = document.getElementById("quote1").innerHTML;
    var secondString = document.getElementById("quote2").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("quote1").innerHTML = secondString;
    document.getElementById("quote2").innerHTML = firstString;
    setTimeout(swapDiv, 3000);

}
setTimeout(swapDiv, 3000);
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="quote1">I am another quote</div><span>
<div id="quote2">I am yet another quote</div><span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: DOWNVOTER if you don't leave a comment why you downvoted how do we know  whats lacking in the answer? Please give a chance to the person who answered improve as well. Thanks in advance for "To Be Left Comment".

Answer (score -1):

### HTML

```
<div id="div1">quote 1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">quote 2</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
i=0;
setInterval(function(){
    if(i%2 == 0)
        $('#div1').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#div2').fadeIn('slow')
        })
    else
        $('#div2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#div1').fadeIn('slow')
        })    
    i++;
}, 2000)
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/77Mg4/1/)